# Return a value and show plot when running a function

Tags: python, matplotlib, holoviews

So while writing my functions, for analyzing the data I like to built the functionality to display data, it helps me debug.

In matplotlib with jupyter notebook I can use the following code to show a plot and return a value:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def testwithmatplotlib(num, plotdata = True):
    x = np.arange(num)
    y = x * x
    if plotdata:
        plt.scatter(x, y)
        plt.show()
    return(y)
resmat = testwithmatplotlib(8)
```

[image: with matplotlib]

In holoviews, with jupyter notebook I am using IPython display module as below.
I am not sure if this is good method or no, please suggest if there is a better way to do this.

```
import holoviews as hv
def testwithholoviews(num, plotdata = True):
    x = np.arange(num)
    y = x * x
    if plotdata:
        aplot = hv.Scatter((x, y))
        hv.IPython.display.display_html(aplot)
        plt.show()
    return(y)

 
reshol = testwithholoviews(8)
```

[image: with holoviews]

Answer (score 0):

HoloViews uses the IPython rich display machinery to plot the output of the cell. If you want to invoke that machinery before the cell returns, just call `display`:

```
import holoviews as hv, numpy as np
from IPython.display import display
hv.extension("bokeh")

def testwithholoviews(num, plotdata = True):
    x = np.arange(num)
    y = x * x
    if plotdata:
        display(hv.Scatter((x, y)))
    return y
 
reshol = testwithholoviews(8)
```

[image: Output from display]

Alternatively, you can return the HoloViews object so that it's always visualizable, but then pull the data out of it in the case that you want to inspect it:

```
import holoviews as hv, numpy as np
hv.extension("bokeh")

def testwithholoviews(num, plotdata = True):
    x = np.arange(num)
    y = x * x
    return hv.Scatter((x, y))
 
reshol = testwithholoviews(8)
reshol
```

[image: Output from return val]

Same result either way; just depends whether you want to work with objects with a visual representation, or if you want to treat plots as a side effect.